# OptionParser error on set_default

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Working with optparse i came across with this error and i can't figure out what is going on, an the docs aren't helping me to clarify why this is happening.

Code:

```
formats = ['xml', 'json', 'yaml']
parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage = u, version = v)
parser.add_option('-s', '--src', dest = 'source_file', metavar = 'single source file')
parser.add_option('-f', '--format', dest = 'frmt', type = 'choice', choices = formats)
parser.add_option('-o', '--output', dest = 'output_file')

parser.set_default(frmt = 'xml', output_file = 'doc.xml')
opts, args = parser.parse_args()

gen_doc(opts.source_file, opts.frmt, opts.output_file)
```

Error:

```
$ python main.py -s a -f xml -o a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 29, in main
    parser.set_default(frmt = 'xml', output_file = 'doc.xml')
TypeError: set_default() got an unexpected keyword argument 'frmt'
```

As far as i know `set_default` should recognize the instance members set on `add_option`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is `set_defaults`; note the plural.  `set_default` (in the singular) takes two parameters; a name of an option and its value.

Comment: That error message was totally misleading, or not at all acording to your update.